# Share const let object from another file

Tags: javascript

I have an Object {} in node, const or I can do it and let example:

f.js

```
const fe = {};

function doSomething(string1, string2){
  fe[string1] = string2; // fe {string1 = string2}
}
```

With this way I fill my Object with values witch working just fine I can see the value fine.

Now I want to access this fe from another .js in node and read the values from it example:

e.js

```
function doSomethingElse(){
const Val = fe{};
console.log(Val); // The values from the fe in f.js
}
```

I try different ways with no luck.. any suggestions will be useful

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Pass `fe` into the function as an argument.

Comment: What environment are you working in? Browser, node.js, something else? How do you normally access variables and functions from other files? Do you use some kind of module system? If yes, which one?

Comment: What does "*const or I can do it and let example*" mean?

Answer (score 0):

you need to learn about javascript [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export?retiredLocale=de) and [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import?retiredLocale=de)

e.js

```js
// i added something so you dont only see a empty object
export const fe = {
  test: 'test', //<--------
};

function doSomething(string1, string2) {
  fe[string1] = string2; // fe {string1 = string2}
}
```

f.js

```js
import { fe } from './f.js';
export function doSomethingElse() {
  const Val = fe;
  console.log(Val); // The values from the fe in f.js
}
```

a playable example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-lfttsg?file=f.js,e.js,index.js)

Comment: That I was see was an undefined Objet.. Thank you!! I will try it asap.

Comment: not working in node the import.... throws an error..

Comment: What error? Error messages are important, next time paste the error in your message

Comment: I manage it with changing file to the import. The error was because exist and another import from the same file. Thank you!